# Receive file from ftp to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, ftp

How do I set up a scheduled job in SQL Server 2008 that connects to a ftp server and transfers a file either to a local drive or even better into a table.

I think I can use SSIS (at least that I read) but can't find a tutorial or like.

If I can just get the file to my local drive then I good but of course the even better solution is a file transfer directly into a table :)

Answer (score 3):

Definetely possible with SSIS.

Use Business Intelligence Studio to design the SSIS package, then you can schedule this package as SQL Agent job.

SSIS can't transfer it directly to the table, but it can download it to temporary file (use FTP task), then load it to table (depends on file format, most likely you'll need to use Data Flow task), and delete file (File System task).